# ¿Como llenar elemento SELECT de HTML con función PHP consultando a MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, php5

Actualmente lleno las "options" de la siguiente manera:

```
<select id="producto_campania" class="form-select form-select-sm nice-select" name="producto_campania[]" required>
    <option selected disabled>
        Selecciona una opción
    </option>
    <?php
        $sentenciaProducto = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM bujic_payboard.productos ORDER BY valor_producto ASC");
        $sentenciaProducto -> execute();
        while ($filasProducto = $sentenciaProducto -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $filasProducto['valor_producto'] . '">' . $filasProducto['nombre_producto'] . '</option>';
        }
        $sentenciaProducto -> closeCursor();
    ?>
</select>
```

Tengo la conexión a la base de datos, está funcionando correctamente todo, bien ahora mi duda es como hago esto pero con una función PHP que retorne la información para llenar el select, honestamente lo había hecho pero no recuerdo exactamente ¿Alguien sabe, que me pueda refrescar la memoria?

Al seguir la respuesta de John, me surgió un error quiero suponer es de scope o vida de las variables de las funciones (pueden leer un poco sobre [Funciones PHP](https://fernando-gaitan.com.ar/aprendiendo-php-parte-10-funciones/))

Declaro la función:
Coloco el método para devolver PDO Objet dentro de la función, pero la instancias de las clases a la conexión a DB fuera de ella me marca el error "**Undefined variable '$conexionBDPayBoard'**" ¿Sí es por el scope de las variables verdad?

```
// Instancias de las clases
$conexionBDPayBoard = new baseDatosPayBoard();
function obtenerOpcionesProductos($condicion = "") {
    // Metodos para devolver objetos PDO
    $conexion = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard();
}
```

Comment: Pues declaras la función, dentro de ella concatenas en una variable en vez de hacer `echo` y retornas el contenido de esa variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una función que se conecte a la base de datos y obtenga los datos que necesitas.
La función puede tomar cualquier parámetro que necesites.

En lugar de imprimir los `option` directamente en el código HTML, almacena los `option` en una variable y retorna esa variable al final de la función.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar la función:

```
function obtenerOpcionesProductos($condicion = "") {
    // Realiza la conexión a la base de datos
    $conexion = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard();

    // Prepara la consulta SQL para obtener los productos
    $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM bujic_payboard.productos" . $condicion . " ORDER BY valor_producto ASC");
    $sentencia -> execute();

    // Almacena los option en una variable
    $opciones = "";
    while ($filas = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $opciones .= '<option value="' . $filas['valor_producto'] . '">' . $filas['nombre_producto'] . '</option>';
    }
    $sentencia -> closeCursor();

    // Retorna las opciones
    return $opciones;
}
```

así se usaría

```
<select id="producto_campania" class="form-select form-select-sm nice-select" name="producto_campania[]" required>
    <option selected disabled>Selecciona una opción</option>
    <?= obtenerOpcionesProductos();?>
</select>
```

Comment: Almacenar las opciones en una variable tipo string (""), tengo las siguientes dudas ¿No debería guardarlas mejor en un array? ¿La sentencia preparada debe ir dentro d un try catch, no? Edite la pregunta para mi 3era duda, la deje en la pregunta al final ¿Puedes despejarme un poco las dudas @John?

Comment: Una duda más, una disculpa... estaba jugando con el código me doy cuenta que al usar las etiquetas "completa" (<?php?>) no carga el select pero si con <?=?>

Comment: es para ahorrar el echo, `<?=` es equivalente a un `<?php echo`

Comment: y el tema de almacenar un array es muy distinto, hay muchos caminos para llegar a roma, yo solo te muestro uno. en simples palabras se puede hacer de muchas formas.

Comment: Excelente John, sí me sirvió tu respuesta ya de esa me baso para lo que requería ¡Gracias!